# Browser still send HTTP POST request after preflight request does not allow POST method

Tags: request, cors, http-post, http-method

I'm confused about that my API server (NodeJS Express) only allow GET method

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
```

then I make a CORS POST request with header

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-Test-Header': 'TESTING'
}
```

(the purpose is force browser to call OPTIONS request before a POST request). Then I inspect Network Tab in Chrome Debug, it does send 2 request (first with OPTIONS then POST request). The response header of OPTIONS request is:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
```

the question is why it still calls POST request when POST verb is not included in Allow-Methods headers?

Anyone know this please explain to me. Thanks in advance.

P/S: With DELETE or PUT method, it will throw an error

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed
by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

I think with POST method it must throw the same error to indicate the method is not allowed

P/S: I'm still facing about this issue, Does anyone know it and explain to me, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed in your browser that are designed to solve cors issues?

Comment: @Ferrybig, No, I've tested in some pc then recognize that POST request still get called regardless the "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header from previous OPTIONS request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem recently. I found this in [fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch), which I think could be used as a reference for the real http spec since fetch API have to comply to it. According to the step 7, it's said that if **CORS check** returns success, it will go through the step 7.5, which deduces if the **request's method** is valid. We can notice that if the **request's method** is not in the **Access-Control-Allow-Methods** and it's not a **CORS-safelisted method**(GET, POST, HEAD), it will throw an error.

From the above inference, we can know that it's because your preflight passed the **CORS check**, even though the request's method didn't match the **Access-Control-Allow-Methods**, since it was a **CORS-safelisted method**, it would not throw an error.

Considering that, if you want to forbid the POST method, you should not let it pass the **CORS check**. For instance, don't set the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** in the response. It dosen't really matter whatever you set **Access-Control-Allow-Methods**, since it's a **CORS-safelisted method**.